# show assertion message with robolectric

Tags: android, maven, robolectric, android-testing

I'm using maven and robolectric to test my android app and i'd like to see the notes i put into my assertions when they fail. I can't seem to find these anywhere. They don't show up in the console and aren't outputted into the surefire-reports directory.

For example, i'd like to see "Failed because X and Y are not equal" somewhere when this assertion fails.

```
Boolean X = true;
Boolean Y = false;

assertEquals("Failed because X and Y are not equal",X,Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Assert.assertTrue(x);